# How to fix UIPageViewController cutting off content?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, uipageviewcontroller

I am writing an iOS app similar to a book reader. I have a problem with part of the program where I am using a UIPageViewController to transition between the pages.

The hierarchy I am using here looks like this:
`UIContainerViewController -> UIPageViewController -> UIViewController`

The ViewController has a webView as its main view, because the pages I am displaying are in pdf format.

I want to know if there is some way to stop content from being cut off like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r26p2o55y2qdd1i/IMG_0004.PNG
and instead have it curl from off screen.

Thanks!

Comment: Try setting your webView `scalesPageToFit` property to YES.

Comment: I did that... still not what I'm looking for. I don't even know if it's possible. There isn't anything _wrong_ with the program functionally, but I don't think it looks good the way it is.